# While Cassandra compaction Fatal exception in thread CompactionExecutor

Tags: exception, cassandra, cluster-computing, eof, cassandra-0.7

1. I am having cassandra cluster of 12 nodes on EC2 running cassandra-0.8.2.
   While compaction I got the following exception which caused Seed node to get down.
2. Below is the exception stack trace.

> ERROR [CompactionExecutor:31] 2011-12-16 08:06:02,308 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 139) Fatal exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:31,1,main]
>   java.io.IOError: java.io.EOFException: EOF after 430959023 bytes out of 778986868
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableIdentityIterator.(SSTableIdentityIterator.java:149)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableIdentityIterator.(SSTableIdentityIterator.java:90)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableIdentityIterator.(SSTableIdentityIterator.java:74)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.next(SSTableScanner.java:179)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.next(SSTableScanner.java:144)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner.next(SSTableScanner.java:136)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner.next(SSTableScanner.java:39)
>           at org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.CollatingIterator.set(CollatingIterator.java:284)
>           at org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.CollatingIterator.least(CollatingIterator.java:326)
>           at org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.CollatingIterator.next(CollatingIterator.java:230)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ReducingIterator.computeNext(ReducingIterator.java:69)
>           at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
>           at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:135)
>           at org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.FilterIterator.setNextObject(FilterIterator.java:183)
>           at org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.FilterIterator.hasNext(FilterIterator.java:94)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.doCompactionWithoutSizeEstimation(CompactionManager.java:569)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.doCompaction(CompactionManager.java:506)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$1.call(CompactionManager.java:141)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$1.call(CompactionManager.java:107)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by: java.io.EOFException: EOF after 430959023 bytes out of 778986868
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.skipBytesFully(FileUtils.java:229)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexHelper.skipIndex(IndexHelper.java:63)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableIdentityIterator.(SSTableIdentityIterator.java:141)
>           ... 23 more

- It says it is Caused by: java.io.EOFException:
- Is it because of the corrupt sstables?
  if it is, then how to remove or repair those sstables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is indeed caused by corrupt sstables (which may indicate a hardware problem).  My recommendations:

1. Upgrade to the latest stable 0.8.x version of Cassandra.  This will be a drop-in replacement for 0.8.2.
2. Run "nodetool scrub" on the machine having problems
3. Review http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/install/cluster_init -- I recommend two seed nodes per data center, but remember that a seed node is only consulted when restarting nodes, so it's not a big deal to have one down during normal operation